# Trying to use wildcards in bash conditional statement/case mixed with exact alpha char and failing

Tags: bash, wildcard, conditional-statements, alpha

Essentially, I'm testing a variable to ensure it's contents matches a specific time format: 4 digits, am/pm/AM/PM, no spaces (i.e. 1204pm). I've gotten this much to work:

```
tm0=1204pm; [[ $tm0 == [0-2###aApP]* ]] && echo PASS
```

or

```
tm0=1203pm; case $tm0 in [0-2###apAP]*) echo PASS; esac
```

But when I try to specify the last character as "m" (Originally I was trying for [Mm] but that didn't work either) it fails.

```
tm0=1204pm; [[ $tm0 == [0-2###aApP]m ]] && echo PASS
```

Any help, please and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using globs:

```
[[ $tm0 == [01][0-9][0-5][0-9][aApP][mM] ]]
```

Note that this will validate, e.g., `1900pm`. If you don't want that:

```
[[ $tm0 == @(0[0-9]|1[0-2])[0-5][0-9][aApP][mM] ]]
```

This uses [extended globs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching). Note that you *don't* need `shopt -s extglob` to use extended globs inside `[[ ... ]]`: in section [Condition Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs), for the doc about `[[ ... ]]` you can read:

> When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), as if the `extglob` shell option were enabled.

To use this feature in a `case` statement, you need to enable `extglob`.

---

Using regex:

```
[[ $tm0 =~ ^(0[0-9]|1[0-2])([0-5][0-9])([aApP][mM])$ ]]
```

With these groupings, you get the hour in `BASH_REMATCH[0]`, the minutes in `BASH_REMATCH[1]` and the am/pm in `BASH_REMATCH[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

bash patterns are not regular expressions. They are also not Java patterns, which I think is what you're trying to use (although it's not at all clear).

You can (and should) read the [bash manual chapter on pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), which is a complete list of pattern features. In that, you will see that:

- `[...]` matches a single character which is one of the characters in the enclosed character class description
- `*` matches any number of arbitrary characters

So `[0-2###apAP]*` matches one of the characters <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, or <kbd>P</kbd>, followed by any number of characters (including 0).

What I think you are looking for is:

[01][0-9][0-5][0-9][aApP][mM]

although that is slightly generous since it will match, for example, 1300pm ("It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.")

Comment: Thanks. That was pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: @JamesLingo: `*` matches any number of anything. `[...]` and `m` match a single character. So `[0-2]m` can only match exactly two characters, like `1m`, whereas `[0-2]*` matches anything which starts with a small digit.

Comment: Yeah totally understood that from the beginning but it wasn't triggering when I was using brackets for each character because I tried using '#' as a wildcard (any number). When I started getting results with all wildcards in a single bracket, I went the wrong direction.